# Add new items to dictionary inside a class

Tags: python, function, class

I am stuck with a simple addition of elements to a dictionary but in this case there are inside a class and a function this is my code

```
class Counter:
     id : str   
     _items: dict
  
     def __init__(self, ID: str):
          '''creates a new counter with a given ID'''
          self.id = ID 
                    
          #dict[str, list[int, float]]
  
     def add(self, item_name: str, amount: int, price_of_unit: float)-> None:
          '''Adds amount of items with item_name and specifies price_of_unit. You can assume that every addition for the same item_name will have the same price_of_unit.'''
          self_items={}
          self_items[item_name]=[amount,price_of_unit]
          return self_items
```

Then I create the counter with this

```
mycounter = Counter("001")
```

Then I want to add items to it

```
mycounter.add("dogfood",5,30.0)
```

The problem that it adds only one item and overwrite it when I add it. I had a look at the dictionary documentations and I tested it outside the funtion, but I am probably missing something, any help?

Comment: Create the dict in `__init__` as `self._items = {}`, and in `add` just `self._items[...] = ...`…?!

Comment: Your annotations are wrong for add method : this method return a dict and not None. In addition, you don't need to define `id: str` and `_items: dict` in class if you do it in `__init__` method.

Comment: I have added the return so I could see the dictionary, it an exercise, I will remove the return once completed

Comment: `self_items` only exists within the `add()` method. You need to use `self._items` instead (you defined it earlier in the class), follow on @deceze comment and declare it in `__init__`